# INFO: Ignoring response <403 webpage_name> HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

**I'm constantly getting the 403 error in my spide**r, *note my spider is just scraping the very firsst page of the website, it is not doing the pagination*. Could this be a clue? These are a few things that I have done to see if the issue resolves, these two advices were given to similar questions here in stackoverflow:

1. I have changed my user agent, didn't work.
2. I have set handle_httpstatus_list = [403] in settings.py, didn't work.

This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

#myclass
class QrocasasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'qrocasas'
    page_number = 2
    #functions to clean data

    #starting my request 
    def start_requests(self):
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url='https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-o-departamentos-o-terrenos-en-venta-en-queretaro.html',
                wait_time=5,
                callback=self.parse
                )
    
    #scraping
    def parse(self, response):
        homes = response.xpath("//div[@class='postingCardTop']/div[2]")
        for home in homes:
            yield {
                'price': home.xpath("normalize-space(.//div[1]/div[1]/span/text())").get()
                # 'location': home.xpath(".//div[@class='tile-location one-liner']/b/text()").get(),
                # 'description': home.xpath(".//div[@class='tile-desc one-liner']/a/text()").get(),
                # 'bedrooms': home.xpath(".//div[@class='chiplets-inline-block re-bedroom']/text()").get(),
                # 'm2': home.xpath(".//div[@class='chiplets-inline-block surface-area']/text()").get(),
            }
        next_page = 'https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-o-departamentos-o-terrenos-en-venta-en-queretaro-pagina-'+ str(self.page_number) + '.html'
        if int(self.page_number) < 10:
            self.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page,callback=self.parse)
```

This is the error I get:

```
2021-12-08 10:53:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-o-departamentos-o-terrenos-en-venta-en-queretaro-pagina-2.html> (referer: https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-o-terrenos-o-departamentos-en-venta-en-queretaro.html)
2021-12-08 10:53:41 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.inmuebles24.com/casas-o-departamentos-o-terrenos-en-venta-en-queretaro-pagina-2.html>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2021-12-08 10:53:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-12-08 10:53:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:59145/session/2e39a7f0-1ffa-48e7-ad30-9ca71202c44a {}
2021-12-08 10:53:42 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://127.0.0.1:59145 "DELETE /session/2e39a7f0-1ffa-48e7-ad30-9ca71202c44a HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2021-12-08 10:53:42 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
```

Comment: The url is protected by cloudflare

Comment: How did you figure that out?

Comment: I figured it out by scrapy shell